# How to create dynamic unknown number of buttons on runtime ? How to add each of them a action listener to all buttons on runtime?

Tags: ios, swift3

[image]

**I want build interface like this. user will input range of buttons to be displayed. I am new at iOS development. I don't know how to do this all on runtime plz help..
I want to store the number of pressed and unpressed buttons in database how can I achieve this any solution for this.**

*Thank you in advance*

Comment: Try it by yourself and show your code when you run into an issue. SO is not a place where people will code your app for you.

Comment: I am not asking for code for your kind information. I am just asking how to add buttons on runtime with dynamic range.And one more thing I have developed this logic in android. I am new at iOS devlpmnt so I am asking. thank you for  suggestion @deadbeef

Comment: Start with step 1 - how to create a button (tip: search for `create uibutton programmatically swift 3`). When you've learned that, go to step 2 - how to create a grid of objects. Then step 3 - how to use a data source to track the state of your objects. Step 4 (or somewhere later) will be putting that all together. If you run into a specific problem, *then* you can ask a specific question.

Comment: Thank You! @DonMag actually I have searched a lot for add action listener to dynamic button but I am not getting it. So Plz give the solution how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hi you can achieve this by using collectionView(is the efficient approach) or by adding the buttons
So while adding button just add a tag of button with +1 and when user click the button just fetch button tag and you will get which button is clicked.
Please find below sample

var prevBtn = 0

func addButton()

let button = UIButton()
button.tag = prevBtn.tag + 1
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleButtonAction), 
for:.touchUpInside)
prevBtn = button.tag
}

func handleButtonAction(button: UIButton){

print(button.tag)

}

Thanks
```

Comment: Thank you @Optimus This collectionView idea actually worked for me. Thank man

Answer (score 1):

addTarget is function for button like action listener in android.

dynamicButtonInstance.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister), for: .touchUpInside)

handleRegister is a function in class.

Creation of button is

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 50 , g: 80, b: 130)
button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister), 
for:.touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Thank you bro @SP74 . I  managed to create button runtime and also now I can add action listener to iit at runtime. Thank you so much.